# Lightbox for Large Image - Scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I am using [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) Plugin. it works fine until the images are large enough and has to be shown at full resolution so that people can read content on the image.

I am looking on how i can have a lightbox modal window open and the window should be scrollable so that the user can scroll if needed vertically or horizontally to view the entire width and height of the image.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/navami/projects/nandini